# Fundamental group of this subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

How to compute the fundamental group of the following topological space?

$$\{(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2\ |\ z_1\neq0,\ z_2\neq0,\ z_1\neq z_2\}$$

I am having no idea..

Comment: You’re removing the $x$-axis, $y$-axis, and the diagonal.  One can also imagine this configuration in $\mathbb{C}^2\cong \mathbb{R}^4$. Some care is needed for the diagonal. So I suspect you can try and find a homotopy that makes things easier.

Comment: Oh,, I just realize that it is exactly the Artin braid group $B_3$. Amazing

Comment: @likeeatingoctopus Then you should write an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is the pure braid group $PB_3$. Because this space is homotopy to the configuration space $F_3(\mathbb{C})$. check this wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(mathematics)